# hover and moveout not giving expcted result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Because I am creating DOM using Jquery it was difficult to copy the output so i am adding one image of code that i have captured using one tool

[image]

i have attached hover and mouseout event to `id='nf1'` using this code

```
$("#nf"+n).hover(function(){
    $("#nf"+$(this).attr("post_id")+"post_delete").show();
});
$("#nf"+n).mouseout(function(){
    $("#nf"+$(this).attr("post_id")+"post_delete").hide();
});
```

Here n is post_id and i am looping all post_id got from response.This attach events but not giving expected behaviour Like when mouse over to `id='nf1post_delete'` it is hide

Please ask if any doubts

Comment: Have you tried .mouseenter() and .mouseleave()? jQuery demonstrates the differences between them and .mousein() and .mouseout() with a side-by-side comparison demo on the documentation for each of the four functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're describing this, you will actually want to pass two functions to `.hover()`, one for the action on mouseenter and one for the action on mouseleave. You can pass only one function to `.hover()`, but it will run that function when you roll over and when you roll out.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

So, try this instead:

```
$("#nf"+n).hover(function(){
    $("#nf"+$(this).attr("post_id")+"post_delete").show();
},function(){
    $("#nf"+$(this).attr("post_id")+"post_delete").hide();
});
```

The `.mouseout()` function isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

At first, .hover() includes mouseenter and mouseleave. Do you put both function in there and don't use an additional event. Also don't use mouseout(). Use instead mouseleave().

So you either use hover(function(){},function(){}); alone, or you use mouseenter() and mouseleave().

Answer (score 1):

Since you're manipulating the DOM, I'm going to recommend using jQuery `.on()` instead of `.hover()`:

```
$(document).on({
  mouseover: function(){
    $("#nf"+$(this).attr("post_id")+"post_delete").show();
  },
  mouseout: function(){
    $("#nf"+$(this).attr("post_id")+"post_delete").hide();
  }
}, "#nf"+n);
```

If you're creating something in the DOM after the page has loaded, `.on()` helps to attach event listeners to it.

[jQuery API for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)